# ¿Por qué decimos que estamos "empanados" cuando tenemos la mente confusa?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

En España se usa bastante en conversaciones coloquiales la expresión **estar empanado/a**.

> -Pásame el pan
>
> -¿El qué?
>
> -Estás algo empanado esta mañana. Dije que si me puedes pasar el pan.

El propio DRAE lo contempla:

> [**empanada mental**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ElL4pFW)
>
> 1. f. coloq. Confusión de ideas.

Mirando sin embargo las definiciones de [*empanar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ElM70Z6) no observo ninguna acepción que pueda ayudar a entender el origen de la expresión.

¿Alguien sabe por qué se usa? Además, ¿se usa en otros países de habla hispana?

Comment: No se usa en Colombia

Comment: En Chile tampoco.

Comment: Sería interesante saber desde cuándo se usa. Lo mismo viene de la "empana mental" que tenían los de Martes y Trece con la [empanadilla de Móstoles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eQJoaFlukI). Ese [sketch](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23156/5481) dejó una huella profunda en muchos... (es de sus más memorables). No me extrañaría que después de esa Nochevieja la gente usase la expresión de "tener/llevar una empanada" para expresar confusión a raíz del sketch. Eso también explicaría que no se use en otros países (donde ese dúo cómico no es conocido).

Comment: En latinoamerica no utilizamos la palabra "empanado" pero coincido con el punto de vista de otro participante - podría ser un adjetivo "creado" de la palabra empanada [las cuales llevan un largo y dificil procedimiento] .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi teoría es que viene del francés. "Panne" quiere decir fallo y se dice comúnmente que algo está "en panne" cuando está dañado o no funciona.

El castellano habría incorporado esto y pasado de "en panne" a "empanado".

Comment: Esto también coincide con que se usa especialmente en España y no en los paises latinomericanos.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Esta respuesta contiene la teoría más plausible de todas las que se han propuesto hasta ahora, en mi opinión. ¡Anímate a registrarte en el sitio y darnos más respuestas como esta!

Comment: Según un diccionario de francés consultado, "[panne](http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=panne)" significa "important dysfonctionnement physiologique momentané, qui n'est ni une maladie, ni une pathologie". Vamos, que estar "en panne" en francés significa exactamente lo mismo que "estar empanado" en español, lo que le da aún más credibilidad a esta teoría.

Comment: Pues me convence la teoría, luego la marco como aceptada. ¡Gracias Antonio y espero que hasta pronto!

Answer (score 3):

Pura especulación, pero quizás más que con **empanar** tenga que ver, en sentido figurado, con la segunda acepción de [**empanada**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ElL4pFW): (Masa de pan rellena de carne, pescado, verdura, etc., cocida en el horno.), porque los distintos elementos del relleno estén entremezclados, y sea difícil separarlos con claridad.

Comment: ¡Interesante hipótesis!

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que porque lo que está empanado culinariamente (rebozado con pan rallado) es, figuradamente, más "espeso" que sin empanar...

Answer (score 2):

Hay una treta en la esgrima de espada y daga que se llama "la empanada", en la cual se sujeta la hoja del contrario con ambas armas por ambos lados dejándole atontado cuando está bien realizada. Dado que muchas expresiones tienen un origen anecdótico tal vez ese sea el de esta.

Comment: Creo que para esta es difícil aportar referencias, pero alguna sí que encontrado acerca de [la técnica de la empanada](https://books.google.com/books?id=9cX1lNsy0ewC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=la+empanada+esgrima&source=bl&ots=zDzmPWRwYP&sig=z5GFAI5dlG8yMWoTrGqeEbjKtHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH-_729LfZAhVLy1MKHdYLDukQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=la%20empanada%20esgrima&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Resulta curioso, ahora que me doy cuenta, de que la palabra *empanado* ya se usaba en el siglo XVIII, en la época del *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> EMPANADO. Se llama el aposento y pieza de la casa, que está por todas partes cercada y rodeada de otras piezas, de calidad que por ninguna parte recibe las priméras luces, ni és batida de los áires.

Se puede entonces entender su uso figurado cuando tu cerebro no tiene las suficientes luces y el aire viciado. De hecho existen textos que parecen usar esta palabra de esta forma figurada:

> *Tomóle una mano y, aunque se estaban mano sobre mano, no holgaban. Hacíase Eneas la señora con Policarpo, para ser Nerón con su dinero. Acaricióle y, arrimándose a un figón, le mostraron semblante empanado cuando él estaba empenado, porque dejó el papel en la tienda de las valonas. Mas, sin poder resistillo, dijo doña Ur[rac]a:
>
>   —A propósito es el tiempo para unas empanadas inglesas.*
>
> Baptista Remiro de Navarra, "Los peligros de Madrid", 1646 (España).

Sin embargo, no veo más usos figurados de la palabra hasta ya épocas muy recientes (década de 1990). Por lo que considero que su retorno al idioma haya podido venir dada o bien por un rescate de la palabra antigua, o más plausiblemente por influencia del francés "en panne", como afirma Antonio Avila en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25897/12637).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Una consulta a los diccionarios marítimos más antiguos (de 1830 y 1849) que aparecen [en este enlace](https://sectormaritimo.es/recopilacion-de-diez-diccionarios-maritimos) muestra que el término "empanado" se usaba en náutica en el español del s. XIX... pero no con el significado que nos ocupa. Y [una consulta de "panne" en un tratado sobre la *lingua franca* mediterránea](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&id=_DwHAQAAIAAJ&dq=Dictionnaire%20de%20la%20langue%20franque&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=panne) parece indicar que las palabras usadas en [sabir](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabir) para ese concepto no tenían nada que ver con el término en francés. Luego lo más probable es que efectivamente se tomase prestada del francés con posterioridad, tal como apunta la respuesta aceptada.

---

Estaba poniendo un comentario a la [interesante respuesta de Antonio Avila](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25897/13628), pero me he quedado sin espacio...

Me encanta la hipótesis de que venga del francés. No obstante, me sorprende un poco que tal acepción no aparezca en el Larousse, que es uno de los diccionarios más famosos de francés. Por otra parte, viendo que [Charlie apunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25898/13628) que en español se usa desde mediados del s. XVII (que luego desaparezca del registro escrito, no quiere decir que no se usase oralmente), me ha asaltado la duda del huevo y la gallina, es decir: ¿qué fue antes: el "empanado" español o el "en panne" francés?

Para empezar, he consultado un diccionario de francés de 1701 y [ninguno de los ocho significados para PANNE](https://goo.gl/gcTpmb) coincide con el de la respuesta. Esto apuntaría a que el significado de "algo que ha dejado de funcionar" sería posterior a los inicios del x. XVIII. De momento va ganando el español por un siglo.

Después me he ido al Trèsor, y ahí sí que se recoge ese significado [en la tercera entrada (PANNE<sup>3</sup>)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panne), y nos ofrece una especie de histórico de la evolución de las acepciones:

- desde 1879, literalmente "dejar de funcionar un mecanismo", que es el origen propuesto;
- desde 1759, con un significado parecido: "imposibilidad de actuar (un regimiento)", de donde se podría interpretar "estar empanado" como "estar bloqueado, no poder actuar";
- desde 1611 *mettre en panne*, significando una maniobra marina para hacer que un barco se pare poniéndolo en contra del viento; la cual a su vez viene de,
- desde 1573, *Bouter vent en penne* que es cuando el viento sopla de tal forma que pega las velas al mástil y el barco se para porque pierde el viento.

Viendo estas "etimologías", quizá el origen real de la expresión por la que se pregunta sea, como en tantos otros casos, un término marinero: *"en panne"* / "empanado" como palabra para indicar que un barco se ha quedado parado porque ha perdido el viento, y de ahí su extensión a cuando una persona se queda embobada, "parada".

<s>Me falta consultar diccionarios marítimos antiguos y, si puedo, alguno de [sabir](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabir) para confirmar si "empanado" se usaba en español con ese significado antes que en francés, o si realmente nos ha llegado de nuestros amigos gabachos.</s>

Como nota curiosa, hoy en día en francés *empanner* significa "trasluchar", que sería la evolución del *mettre en panne* solo que completando el giro para que el barco, en vez de quedarse *en panne*, haga justo lo contrario: recupere el viento por la banda contraria y siga navegando.

Answer (score 0):

A ver. Como en todos los países hay expresiones que no vienen de algo preciso.

Yo como española te digo "estás empanado" es que estás atontando que estás en lapsus. Si lo quieres relacionar con algo... es como con la frase estás espeso... que quiere decir que estás lento, que piensas con retraso.

Como cuando tienes un día de esos que no te enteras de nada... ni de lo más obvio... pero supongo que si quieres relacionar "estar empanado" a algo supongo que es eso "estar espeso" que es otra frase que quiere decir lo mismo.

- Estás espeso
- Estás empanado
- Estás en babia
- Estás obtuso

No se frases que quieren decir que uno no se entera o que está lento en cuanto a reacción. Espero haber ayudado.

Comment: No, si el significado lo tengo claro :) Lo que preguntaba es el origen de la expresión. ¿Lo sabes? Si es así, dale a [edit] para añadir esa parte.

Comment: María, bienvenida a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entneder un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Echale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder _realmente_ a la pregunta y el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenida de nuevo. Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible explicación:

> Su origen lo tiene en Andalucía, donde lo emplean a modo de comparación, exageración, frase u ocurrencia. ¿Y cómo surgió? Estaba  referido al soldado que se comporta con ingenuidad e inocencia ante cualquier estímulo o situación, es decir, que está como atontado. Originariamente, al expresión alude al hecho de estar empachado de tanto comer (lit. ‘lleno de pan’), lo que produce lentitud de sus reflejos (VI. 1972).

La fuente ([Expresión: Tener una empanada mental](https://productoszabala.com/es/blog/expresion-tener-una-empanada-mental-n24)) no parece terriblemente fiable, pero la misteriosa referencia "(VI. 1972)" sugiere que se ha copiado de algún libro.