# "Sketch" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

I was reading [*Polònia dedica su sketch final a Junqueras y los exconsellers encarcelados*](http://vertele.eldiario.es/verteletv/Polonia-dedica-Junqueras-exconsellers-encarcelados_2_1956724309.html), where they talk about the [Catalan TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%B2nia) where a sketch about jailed politicians took place.

We all know what a sketch is in a context of TV shows:

> a short play or slight dramatic performance, as one forming part of a vaudeville program.
>
> ([Thesaurus.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sketch?s=t))

However, I struggle to find a correspondence in Spanish. Even [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=sketch) mentions *sketch* as the "standard" translation into Spanish.

I thought about [***corto***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B36eFH7), short for [*cortometraje*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3AHvXk), but this applies to movies.

Is there any native Spanish word for *sketch*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to [Charlie's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23157/5481), the correspondence in Spanish is the accepted anglicism `sketch`. From DRAE:

> [sketch](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y32fnaH)
>
> Voz ingl.
>
> 1. m. Escena **breve**, normalmente **cómica**, que con otras de las mismas características se integra en un conjunto teatral, cinematográfico o televisivo.

Which could indicate that there is no direct equivalent in Spanish.

It is indeed difficult to find in Spanish something that conveys at the same time "Escena breve" and "cómica" which could be applied to either theater, cinema or TV, since for example [número](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QiamBaG)

> 6. m. Cada una de las partes o actuaciones de que se compone el programa de un espectáculo público

doesn't convey *brevity* nor the essence of *humor*. Same with [acto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0cnCBhK) in its fourth aception (*Cada una de las partes principales en que se pueden dividir las obras escénicas.*)

But you also have `farsa`

> [farsa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HeYCX04)
>
> 1. f. Obra de teatro **cómica**, generalmente **breve** y de carácter satírico.

which as Chalie's answer originally applies to **theater**, but probably can be used  in other media like TV, cinema or Internet. Similarly

> [sainete](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X07vOPP)
>
> 1. m. Obra teatral en uno o más actos, **frecuentemente cómica**, de ambiente y **personajes populares**, que se representa como función independiente.
> 2. m. Pieza dramática en un acto, de **carácter popular y burlesco**, que se representaba como intermedio o al final de una función.

which could apply better in this case due to the connotations of using "popular characters".

Comment: To me _número_ comes closer to sketch than it appears to do for you. I am not sure it is essential for it to be comical.

Comment: @mdewey In Spanish a *sketch* is always comical.

Answer (score 3):

Por recuperar un término algo desusado, ¿qué tal este?

> [**entremés**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FmbyiDZ)
>
> 2. m. Pieza teatral de carácter cómico y de un solo acto, que originalmente se representaba en el entreacto de una comedia.

Vale que el término se usa en televisión y no en el teatro, pero a fin de cuentas hablamos de piezas de corta duración en las que actores interpretan papeles cómicos.

Comment: Hace algunas décadas, en los primeros programas de *El Chavo del 8* y de *El Chapulín Colorado*, al inicio solían ofrecer *un sabroso entremés (sic.)*

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a Spanish word for "sketch". However, the Spanish word is not used commonly. "Sketch" is more used.

Comedians in Mexico use "sketch" as a normal word and will frown upon more proper words, like *entremés* (a very old word from the XVI century), for instance.

Comment: "Sketch" and "entremés" were already covered in the preexisting answers, So, as it is right now, **this answer is just a comment on either answer** (or both) or the question. Please, use your votes if you agree with the existing content and make good use of comments. If you are going to provide a new answer try to add something meaningful not covered in the existing questions, instead of adding redundant content. Also, I disagree that Sketch  "is not used commonly" since, as you say, is the preferred, most widespread word to refer to this small play.

Comment: No, "entremes" is not used. People on stage use "sketch".